# Display full links within cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I've read about the cross-domain policy and the restrictions it has in terms of access when we don't have access to both parent and child domains in order to allow access.

However, I was wondering if I have access to parent page and not child page of the iframe is it still impossible to get the iframe to display all links within as href links like http://example.com and not [example](http://example.com)?

I've seen some scripts before but these are all server side and the links within the iframe are adjusted based on user's country so these scripts don't serve my purpose

All help appreciated

Comment: have tried to fetch via dom element however like already mentioned this comes out to server location (ie Brazil) and I'm sitting in UK when testing

Comment: *get the iframe to display all links within as href links* is not clear.. Maybe provide a more specific example, ideally what the HTML looks like now and what you have in mind?

Comment: the links are currently keywords within the other domain. However I want to display the full destination link instead of the keyword (tailored to users location). I know this is something to be changed via the other domain and I have no access to it. However, is there any way I can display this link to the user either by getting it from the dom or iframing it any other way where the link is displayed in its full form and not keyword based but client side